# Можно ли сделать пунктирную линию как в примере, средствами css?

Tags: html, css

Можно ли сделать такую пунктирную линию , как в примере только средствами css, или проще сделать картинкой?
Интересует именно какой то оправданный способ, к примеру делать её дивами не хочу...

[image: Пример линии]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
hr {
  border:none;
  border-top:1px dotted #f00;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#fff;
  height:1px;
  width:100%;
}

hr.ex2 {
  border:none;
  border-top:3px dotted #aaa;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#fff;
  height:1px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
string
<hr>
string2
<hr class="ex2">
string3
```

Смотрите также [Styling <hr> with CSS](http://www.sovavsiti.cz/css/hr.html)

Comment: так это просто точки`..................`

Comment: @Sergey ну да, как у вас в примере, приведенный  в вопросе